# Do Veemon, Hawkmon, Armadillomon, & Wormmon Have Personal Ultimate Forms or Just DNA Ultimate Forms?

Tags: digimon

So, the reason I ask this is because there are 3 sets of DNA Digivolutions that occur in the series to give these 4 an Ultimate level:

Stingmon (Wormmon's Champion Form) + ExVeemon (Veemon's Champion Form)=Paildramon

Gatomon + Aquilamon (Hawkmon's Champion Form)=Silphymon

Ankylomon (Armadillomon's Champion Form) + Angemon=Shakkoumon

However, both Gatomon and Patamon have their own personal Ultimate forms that do not require DNA Digivolution (Gatomon's being Angewomon and Patamon's being MagnaAngemon)

What makes this interesting is that Ken (Wormmon's partner) ends up with the Crest of Kindness mid-way through Season 2 and the purpose of the Crests initially in Season 1 was to allow Digimon partners to Digivolve to the Ultimate form once the corresponding partner exhibited the trait of said Crest (i.e. Sora's Crest of Love activating after Sora, a character skeptical of being capable of love, expresses love towards Birdramon when she is nearly killed in a battle with Myotismon, allowing her to Digivolve to her Ultimate form, Garudamon)

Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, but there's no Adventure-canon answer.

Before expanding on that, consider that digimon don't necessarily have a single digivolution path. Even within the Adventure canon, we've seen examples of the the same partner digimon being able to digivolve into different forms - specifically, SkullGreymon instead of MetalGreymon in the original series, MetalGreymon (Virus) instead of MetalGreymon in the 02 series, and Ophanimon instead of Magnadramon in Tri. So it's probably not fair to say that the partner digimon have "personal" ultimate forms as much as it might be "preferred" or "typical."

The digivices "serve to channel the emotional energy of the DigiDestined, allowing their Digimon partners to digivolve." [(source: Digimon Wiki)](https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Digivice#Digimon_Adventure_Digivice) When this emotional energy is expended, the digimon reverts back to their standard form (or lower, if a particularly large amount of energy was used), and even this standard form is not consistently the same level, such as Gatomon being Champion-level in day-to-day activities.

So in some sense, digimon do digivolve on their own based on some form of age, experience, or the like, which explains the majority of non-partner higher form digimon. The digivice then allows partner digimon to digivolve further temporarily. As life forms made of data, this is typically explained based on whether they've "downloaded" enough data, which makes them stronger.

While it's not clear what specifically determines which form is used, the examples above all involve unusual circumstances as compared to when each normally digivolves. SkullGreymon comes about when Tai attempts to force Greymon's digivolution in an improper show of Courage. MetalGreymon (Virus) is forced by the controlling energy of a Dark Spiral. Ophanimon results from Kari's emotional breakdown during the closing scenes of Movie 5 in Tri.

When we consider other sources of canon, such as the video games, we see much more branching digivolution trees. If we consider *Digimon: Cyber Sleuth*, as a recent example, Veemon has six different forms it can digivolve in to, depending on stats and levels: the Champion forms ExVeemon, Veedramon, Lobomon, and Strikedramon; and the Armor forms Flamedramon and Magnamon when in possession of the relevant DigiEggs. Notably, in the case of Magnamon, even this is not exclusively achievable by Veemon. Guardromon (Gold) also can digivolve to this form in the game.

So while there isn't a canon answer for what Davis's ExVeemon would further digivolve into independently, if it could via a digivice, certainly *an* ExVeemon does have the ability to digivolve to Ultimate form, given the appropriate time and energy, and the same for an Aquilamon and an Ankylomon. There is no Adventure-canon answer for what those forms would be, however.

Answer (score 1):

Late res, but screw it.

The short version is: Yes, they're Paildramon/Dinobeemon/Silphymon/Shakkoumon. The longer version is the following.

The Digimon series as a whole treat DNA Digivolution as one method of leveling up, by using the fusion partner as the power source for the core Digimon, the same role the Crests play.

This is the premise behind the Paildramon and Dinobeemon characters. They are respectively the ExVeemon-dominant and Stingmon-dominant results.

The Ryo Akiyama series of games from way back when (2000) is the main source for this in regards to the Adventure continuity. The second one (Tag Tamers) has the dual-outcome mechanic apply to Shakkoumon/MagnaAngemon and Angewomon/Silphymon as well, while the fourth (Brave Tamer) uses Paildramon and Dinobeemon as a regular part of Veemon's and Wormmon's lines.

For details on the former: http://www.syldra.net/yesterday/wonderswan/ttfaq_ver1-1.txt. The relevant search string is their names.

Comment: Good answer but some pointers to sources would be useful.

Comment: Aren't naming ones enough?

Comment: I did agree it was a good answer, and gave you a vote.  But, if they're available, you could provide links to descriptions of the games, or at least the relevant parts, or a bit more explanation.  I had to review this without really knowing much about Digimon, and while it appears you've covered the necessary points, without a bit of background it's hard to be sure. :)